# How to edit a Class in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, class, seo, edit, nofollow

I want to edit a link on Menu bar of my website [http://affordablyeasybailbonds.com](http://affordablyeasybailbonds.com/). 
I can see a class "menu-menu1-container" in header.php.
have to edit the external links rel="nofollow". Is there any option to edit without accessing FTP files.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no error. I am not a developer. Just want to edit the rel="" attributes of GPS monitoring link on Menu. I tried WordPress Editor option but unable to find the codes.

Answer (score 0):

The menu will typically either be defined within the code of your header.php file in your WordPress template or in the Menu section, depending on the type of template your site uses.

If it's within the Menu setting under "Appearance", that's quite straightforward to edit. If it's within the header.php, you should be careful when editing it, as an error could bring the site down.

Answer (score 0):

I guess best option is to edit menu on *appearance>Menus*, where you can connect with custom link.
Or install a proper plugin like **MaxMegaMenu** .

cheers